# Using dofile and require in conjunction

Tags: lua

In my current project, I am attempting to add some syntax to my project globally by performing a dofile() at the very top of my `main.lua`. I am then requiring a third file that uses what I'm attempting to add as a global in my project; however I receive an error `attempting to index the global value` upon doing so.

For instance, in the example below, I use dofile() in an attempt to make test1:hello() globally available within my project, yet during the process of requiring test2.lua, i receive the error:

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (test2.lua: attempt to index global 'test1' (a nil value))
```

Shouldn't test1 already exist as a global in this case?  How can I get around this?

main.lua:

```lua
dofile('test1.lua')
require('test2')
```

test1.lua

```lua
test1 = {}
function test1:hello()
   print("hello")
end
```

test2.lua

```lua
module('test2')

test1:hello()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in main.lua:

```
require("test2.lua")
```

should be:

```
require("test2")
```

and in test2.lua i had to pass package.seeall as the second param to module() so that it could see values in test1

```
module('test2', package.seeall)
test1:hello()
```

Comment: It would seem that I needed that package.seeall.  I hadn't realized that the module('test2') call would cause that problem.  It turns out that remove the module declaration works as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested the code (in plain Lua 5.1) and it worked my side (I had to replace `require('test2.lua')` by `require('test2')` though).

Maybe it's a problem in your environment. Where are you executing this Lua code. Does it allow global declarations?

If yes, then it sounds as if you are not exactly doing what you say in your question.

Check things like these:

- `dofile('test1.lua')` is *really* executed before `require('test2.lua')`
- The variable names are ok (for example, you have not written `tset1` instead of `test1` in some place)

Comment: Are you sure that's all you changed (I had accidentally added that .lua at the end)?  That exact example with added enter and exit prints at the beginings and ends of files gives me: "enter main"
"enter test 1"
"exit test 1"
"enter test 2"
"lua: ./test2.lua:4: attempt to index global 'test1' (a nil value)"

Comment: I'm positive that's all I changed. The rest, I copy-pasted from your post. What is your environment? Are you inside a videogame, an engine, or what?